# Which takes precedence cacheMode or max-age in app webview?

Tags: android, ios, webview

I don't want to cache any data in the app's webview.
Therefore, I have specified LOAD_NO_CACHE in the cacheMode.
However, the data is still being cached. Some of the data that is being cached has max-age specified in the Cache-Control.
Which one takes precedence, max-age or cacheMode?
I would appreciate it if you let me know.
Thank you.

I specified LOAD_NO_CACHE in the cacheMode, but the data is still being cached.